# How do I delete Generated Souce(jax-ws) in Netbean 6.8 and should I generate the WS client from WSDL based on websit address or from api?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, webservice-client

I attempted this generation of java classes using ws-import in Netbean 6.8.
I wanted to regenerate a jax-ws because there was an error in found in the package ebay.api.paypalapi (which I think the error is due to the wsdl file from Paypal SOAP Api).

Netbean 6.8 doesn't allow one to delete the Generated Souce(jax-ws) so I re-created another ws file using wsdl based on www.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl but it's still not working.

Hope someone advise me what to do to rectify this problem.  Thanks.

Here's the error code:

```
    20-Oct-2012 21:39:18 : Retrieving Location: http://www.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl 

    Retrieved :    https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl 
    Saved at: C:\Documents and Settings\Karen\Desktop\ShoppingCart\src\conf       
    \xml-resources\web-service-references\PayPalSvc\wsdl\www.paypalobjects.com\wsdl\PayPalSvc.wsdl
     Retrieving Location: CoreComponentTypes.xsd 
    Found in document: https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl

    Error: An I/O error occured. Remote host closed connection during handshake
    Retrieving Location: eBLBaseComponents.xsd 
    Found in document: https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl
    Retrieved :    https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/eBLBaseComponents.xsd 
    Saved at: C:\Documents and Settings\Karen\Desktop\ShoppingCart\src\conf     \xml-resources\web-service-        references\PayPalSvc\wsdl\www.paypalobjects.com\wsdl\eBLBaseComponents.xsd
    Retrieving Location: EnhancedDataTypes.xsd 
    Found in document: https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl
    Retrieved :    https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/EnhancedDataTypes.xsd 
    Saved at: C:\Documents and Settings\Karen\Desktop\ShoppingCart\src\conf\xml-resources\web-service-        references\PayPalSvc\wsdl\www.paypalobjects.com\wsdl\EnhancedDataTypes.xsd
    Retrieving Location: CoreComponentTypes.xsd 
    Found in document: https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/eBLBaseComponents.xsd
    Retrieved :    https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/CoreComponentTypes.xsd 
    Saved at: C:\Documents and Settings\Karen\Desktop\ShoppingCart\src\conf \xml-resources\web-service-        references\PayPalSvc\wsdl\www.paypalobjects.com\wsdl\CoreComponentTypes.xsd
    Retrieving Location: EnhancedDataTypes.xsd 
    Found in document: https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/eBLBaseComponents.xsd
    File name already exists with the same content length. Ignoring the file.:
    Retrieving Location: EnhancedDataTypes.xsd 
    Found in document: https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/eBLBaseComponents.xsd
    Retrieving Location: eBLBaseComponents.xsd 
    Found in document: https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/CoreComponentTypes.xsd
    File name already exists with the same content length. Ignoring the file.:
    Retrieving Location: eBLBaseComponents.xsd 
    Found in document: https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/CoreComponentTypes.xsd`
```

Comment: Have you tried the plain `clean`(not `clean and build`) command in netbeans? That's supposed to get rid of all the generated sources.

Answer (score 1):

wsimport can be used manually by yourself.

Try downloading the wsdl file and all the xsd files linked in the wsdl file.
Save the wsdl files as .xml and the xsd as .xsd files.
Modify the wsdl file to point to the local xsd files.

Then try running wsimport by using the following: -

wsimport -keep -verbose -s . -d . -wsdllocation

Then try debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `xsd`s they link each other as well with an import and you get and error when it tries to download it for a second time.

I would download the `wsdl` and all linked `xsd`s to a local folder and try to generate the web service client from there. If your netbeans proxy generator is too stupid to handle this recursion, have a look at [axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html#generating) . If you happen to use maven have a look at [wdl2code](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-wsdl2code-plugin.html).